# Dynamic locale name in multi-language site

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I am developing an application in cakephp 2.3.4, Which is multi-language.

Admin can add any number of new languages.

My question is, When admin decides to add a new language, how resulting locale name should be defined.

Can a locale name be any arbitrary name, given by admin or it should be a dropdown containg all languages code according to language.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your question is a bit 'vague', i.e., will administrators be able to add GNU-locale files (`*.po`), or are you talking about adding translations inside the *database*.

In any case, CakePHP uses locales according to the ISO 639-3 standard see [here](http://www.sil.org/iso639-3) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) for more information. A complete list of those locales can be found inside the [`I10n`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L95) class.

Since you probably also want to switch the locale of PHP *itself* when switching locales, so that, for example, date, money and time-formats will follow the right format for the locale, it's best to stick with those locales and *not* 'invent' your own locales.

See [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). Be aware though, that PHP may use slightly different locale-codes than CakePHP uses. And it will depend on what locales are installed on your server.

To get a list of locales installed on your server, use `locale -a` on the command line. See this page for more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale

### Which techniques to use for localization

A quick summary of techniques to use;

#### Short messages (interface/UI)

In general, locale files are used for *short* pieces of text. Locale-files are therefore mostly used for *fixed* strings, 
for example, strings that are used in the *interface* (like `'are you sure you want to delete this file?' => 'weet u zeker dat u dit bestand wilt verwijderen?`).

#### Longer (fixed) text

For **longer** pieces of text in your application, that are *not* part of the *'content'* (*not* the blog-post, but for example a fixed page with a disclaimer), 
it's best to use separate *views* for translated content, for example;

```
app/Views/MyController/disclaimer_eng.ctp
app/Views/MyController/disclaimer_deu.ctp
app/Views/MyController/disclaimer_fre.ctp
```

#### Content

For the **content** of your website (the part of your website that is managed by the 'user' of the website),
put translations inside the database. This data may be updated frequently and all translations should be updated as well.

*How to implement this*, is really up to you and depends on your situation. CakePHP offers a `Translate` behavior that you can use (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html), but in most of my situations that behavior didn't really fit our needs (IMO it is not very efficient, because it stores translations per-field, per-model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for not being clear.

I am presenting a web form to admin when he want to add a new language. 

Now should i give admin an input box, in which he will provide any name for that language and that name will be used to create a container folder for that language locale.

Or any other different approch should i adopt.

Comment: @Danial The best approach here, is to offer a *dropdown* containing languages that are supported by your system and CakePHP. The *values* of that dropdown should match the locales as described in my answer. The *labels* (visible values) can be named whatever you want. It's important that you use valid locale-codes, otherwise CakePHP or PHP itself may not know how to handle them (as described in my answer as well).

Comment: Thanks @thaJeztah for your response,

Should i use this [`I10n`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L95) link as described by you, and use `protected $_l10nCatalog` array for creatingdrop-down menu.
Also one more thing, i will change `datetime` according to `timezone` provided by user and `currency` will be fixed `$`, so it will not have any effect when user changes the language.

Comment: Since i am first time implementing multi-language through cakephp locale, your comment are proving very valuable to me.
I also want to know which approch is good, storing language specific content in database or using locale files.
What is the best the approch for multi-language site. In which admin can add any number of languages.
And sorry, if i am teasing you much. But i want to learn best approch.

Comment: @Danial I added some suggestions